# What is a "Plutition Camp"?

Tags: terminology, blade-runner, blade-runner-series

Okay, we're deep blue inside baseball here. In the *original* Blade Runner script, Batty's valedictory speech goes like this:

> “I’ve known adventures, seen places you people will never see, I’ve
>   been Offworld and back… frontiers! I’ve stood on the back deck of a
>   blinker bound for the **Plutition Camps** with sweat in my eyes watching
>   stars fight on the shoulder of Orion… I’ve felt wind in my hair,
>   riding test boats off the black galaxies and seen an attack fleet burn
>   like a match and disappear. I’ve seen it, felt it…!”

"Plutition Camps" didn't make it into the final cut, as far as I know. But searching on that phrase reveals results only related to Blade Runner, making "plutition" both a neologism and a [hapax legomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hapax_legomenon) (how do you like them apples?).

Plutition...'plutos'...underworld, maybe? Maybe a prison camp underground? Does anybody have anything more definitive than a half-assed etymology?

Comment: Out of universe, this is clearly a case of some screenwriter just making crap up, isn't it? If so, and considering its hapax legomenon status, it's impossible to come up with an in-universe etymology. I don't see how this can be answerable, unless someone can refute my theory.

Comment: It might have been in Philip K. Dick's source material, and simply isn't indexed. Or it might be discussed in the Biblical flood of secondary material that surrounds BR.

Comment: It's one of the PKDs I haven't read. Is it in DADOES? We should at least be able to rule it out as Dick's own invention, at least. That'd be something like the start of an answer. Also, any idea if he was an extensive note-taker like some other authors? And if so, what happened to his letters and notes?

Comment: Maybe the writer didn't like "Plutonian" and was trying to get something started.

Comment: IIRC the "I've seen things...." speech was originally written by Rutger Hauer during filming.

Comment: *Plutition* is a word in French, it means something like depletion, diminution, reduction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "pluton" is a rock that has been crystallized from slowly cooling magma. 
An example is Granite. A "pluton" may also refer to a distinctive mass of such rock, for example Cardinal Peak in Washington state.  There's also "Plutonism" which can be said to be an archaic word for "volcanism".

A reasonable guess is then that the writer hinted at some **harsh mining operation**. Possibly so harsh that one would prefer android workers there.

*Edit: The screenwriter for Blade Runner was [David Peoples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Peoples), whose father was a geologist. This could explain why a screenwriter would remember a term from geology.*

Comment: And with "camp," it sounds like it could be punitive hard labor.